# Detect an unsubscribe in Apollo graphql server

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

In the Apollo server, when a client user subscribes to a subscription (using WebSocket), we can detect this using the subscription resolver.

But is there also a way to detect an unsubscribe? 
I see the WebSocket sends a `{"id": "1", "type": "stop"}` message, but I don't know how to catch this

So I don't want to know when a user disconnects from the Websocket, but when a user has unsubscribed a subscription with Apollo client.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 15):

I've been having the same issue, cant believe this isn't in-built into GraphQL or covered in the docs.

I found the solution in a github issue which you can read [here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-subscriptions/issues/99)

the way I fixed it was:

added the `withCancel` function to my resolver :

```
const withCancel = (asyncIterator, onCancel) => {
  const asyncReturn = asyncIterator.return;

  asyncIterator.return = () => {
    onCancel();
    return asyncReturn ? asyncReturn.call(asyncIterator) : Promise.resolve({ value: undefined, done: true });
  };

  return asyncIterator;
};
```

then used that in my subscribe:

```
Subscription: {
    update: {
      subscribe: (root, { id, topic }, ctx, info) => {
        logger.info(`start new subscription for ${id}`);
        ActiveMQ(id, topic);

        return withCancel(pubsub.asyncIterator(id), () => {
          console.log(`Subscription closed, do your cleanup`);
        });
      },
      resolve: payload => {
        return payload;
      },
    },
  }
```

Then I handled my logic in the callback provided by `withCancel`, which for me was closing a stomp client and cleaning up the list of active subscribers etc

Comment: It seems crazy that they have a `subscribe: ...` but not an `unsubscribe: ...`. But this worked for me, what a pro answer!

Answer (score 0):

Apollo 2 , if you want to use subscribe with the withFilter function :

```
subscribe: withFilter(
      (payload, variables, context, info) =>
        withCancel(pubsub.asyncIterator(JOIN_LIVE), () => {
           
          console.log("That our variable " , variables);
        }),
      async (payload, response) => {
        try {
          return (
            payload.channel.toString() === response.ChannelRoom.toString()
          );
        } catch (error) {
          return error.message;
        }
      }
```